# ISBN-13 digit check using Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, boolean, isbn

I just started functional programming, using Haskell, and I want to write a short function that checks a 13-digit code and checks if it is an ISBN number.

The formula for the check is:

```
x13 = (10 − ((x1 + 3x2 +x3 + 3x4 +x5 + 3x6 +x7 + 3x8 +x9 + 3x10 +x11 + 3x12)%10))%10
```

(`x1` being the first digit, `x2` the second, ..., `x13` the last digit etc.)

I want the input to be a list so it's easier for me (13 integers, each 0-9).

So something like this (stuff below is simplified):

```
isValid :: [Int] -> Bool
--isValid = True if (lastdigit = formula)    -- can this be done in one (long) line?
```

So, for example:

```
 isValid [ 9, 7, 8, 0, 1, 3, 7, 0, 5, 3, 4, 6, 9 ]
```

should return `True`

I've been trying to do this for a few hours but I'm not good enough at Haskell yet and it's confusing me. Can someone point me in the right direction? I don't know much about Haskell, which is the main problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pattern match on a list of 13 elements, like:

```
isValid :: [Int] -> Bool
isValid [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13] = …
isValid _ = False
```

with `…` the part you still need to fill in. Hint: you can use [**`mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod) to calculate a modulo (in some programming languages that is done with `%`).

Here `x13` is thus the last digit that you can use in the check.

Comment: Hi, could you help me, I'm trying to do something like `isValid [x1, x2, x3] | (x3 = x1 + x2) = True` but not sure what the correct syntax is? E.g. `isValid [x1, x2, x3] | x3 > x1 + x2 = True` has correct syntax but I need to check if x3 is equal, not > or <.

Comment: @Mandingo: you check equality with `==`, so `1 == 1` is `True`, and `1 == 2` is `False`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now and solved my problem. Is there a quicker way to write the code? Let's say if there were many more digits than 13? If so, would that be a better way to do it?

Comment: @Mandingo: usually if there is a pattern, you can use recursion to iterate over the list, or use a function like `zipWith`, etc. to do the recursion for you.